# Not returning the correct output

Tags: java, variables, input

```
public Map<Route, List<Service>> getTimetable() {
    return timetable;
}


public void loadFile() {
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int status = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        try {
            filePath= selectedFile.getPath();
            fileName.setText(selectedFile.getName());
            this.timetable = tr.read(filePath);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Problem accessing file "+ selectedFile.getAbsolutePath(), nameOfFile, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } catch (FormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid file format", nameOfFile, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        } 
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that the timetable being returned in getTimetable is not returning anything, even though I have set it to be something in the loadFile method. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem. We don't have nearly enough information at the moment.

Comment: I can guess: `tr.read(filePath);` throws exception which you catch in your code but do nothing with...

Comment: What exactly is in your `catch` clause?. It could well be something like `/* ignore any error */` in which case you would never know that `this.timetable = tr.read(filePath)` failed and did not initialise your `timetable` member variable.

Comment: The catch statement catches all the problems I have just ommitted from the code. When I do a System.out.println(timetable) in the loadFile method, I get the timetable printed out. However if I do the same in the getTimetable method, no timetable is printed out

Comment: try returning `this.timetable` from `getTimetable()`

Comment: does not appear to be working

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough code to be sure, but I would suggest :

```
public Map<Route, List<Service>> getTimetable() {
loadFile();
    return timetable;
}
```

Or, did you call your loadFile before? In the same instance?

Comment: Hiya thanks for your reply! I have already tried your code suggestion, and it does not appear to be returning anything